# Find the generators of a non-cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

I would like to know how to find the generators of a non-cyclic group in general. For example a group of $2\times2$ matrices with integer entries and determinant equal to one.

Comment: So this is a volume-preserving group acting on the plane, which means every element of the group either (1) rotates the plane about the origin, or (2) reflects the plane through a line, or (3) stretches the plane by factor $\alpha$ in one principal direction, and compresses by the same factor in the other principal direction, or (4) a combination of two or more of (1), (2), (3).  This should get you started.

Comment: For the generators of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262337/which-pairs-of-matrices-generate-sl2-mathbbz), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144759/generators-for-psl2-mathbbz-with-a-specific-property?rq=1), etc.

Comment: For any group $G$, the set $G$ is a generating set of $G$. So, for example, the set $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is a generating set of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. I suspect this is not the answer you were looking for, in which case you should probably go study the concept of a "generating set" and try to formulate a better question.

Answer (score 2):

It does not make sense in general to speak of **the generators** of a group. Some infinite groups are generated by finitely many elements while some are not. Even if a set of finitely many generators exists, there is no guarantee it is unique. For example the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_p$ is generated by any element coprime to $p$.

Comment: But I face the problem how to find generators of a non-cyclic group. I've never do this task. Actually, I have the task with matrices $2\time2$ mentioned in the ask above. And I have no idea how to do it in this "non-cyclic" way.

Comment: Sorry, $ 2\times 2$. I can't edit it.